# Emulate an Intersect in MySQL w/ multiple tables and Join

Tags: mysql, sql, intersect

I need to emulate an Intersect query in MySQL.

```
    SELECT c.cust_code, cust_fname, cust_lname  
      FROM lgcustomer c JOIN lginvoice i ON c.cust_code = i.cust_code 
      WHERE employee_id = 83649 
    INTERSECT 
    SELECT c.cust_code, cust_fname, cust_lname  
      FROM lgcustomer c JOIN lginvoice i ON c.cust_code = i.cust_code  
      WHERE employee_id = 83677 
    ORDER BY cust_lname, cust_fname;
```

I have tried to use EXISTS but have not been successful. I think I am joining wrong?

```
    SELECT C.CUST_CODE, CUST_FNAME, CUST_LNAME
      FROM LGCUSTOMER C JOIN LGINVOICE I ON C.CUST_CODE = I.CUST_CODE
      WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 83649
      AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM LGCUSTOMER C JOIN LGINVOICE I ON C.CUST_CODE = I.CUST_CODE
                 WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 83677)
    ORDER BY CUST_LNAME, CUST_FNAME;
```

The tables are:

+-------------+
| Customer    |
+-------------+
| Cust_code   |
| Cust_Fname  |
| Cust_Lname  |
+-------------+

and
+--------------+
| LGINVOICE    |
+--------------+
| Cust_code    |
| Employee_ID  |
+--------------+

And I need a query to pull all the Customer codes that have an invoice from two unique Employees (83649 and 83677)

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do? Are your question the last paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . aggregation comes to mind:

```
SELECT c.cust_code, cust_fname, cust_lname  
FROM lgcustomer c JOIN
     lginvoice i
     ON c.cust_code = i.cust_code 
WHERE employee_id IN ( 83649, 83677 )
GROUP BY c.cust_code, cust_fname, cust_lname 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT employee_id) = 2;
```

This also removes duplicates, as does `INTERSECT`.

Comment: Yes this works perfectly! I am still learning SQL, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could emulate a intersect using the inner joij between the two subqueries

```
select * from  (
  SELECT c.cust_code, cust_fname, cust_lname  
  FROM lgcustomer c 
  JOIN lginvoice i ON c.cust_code = i.cust_code 
  WHERE employee_id = 83649 
) t1 
INNER JOIN  (
  SELECT c.cust_code, cust_fname, cust_lname  
  FROM lgcustomer c 
  JOIN lginvoice i ON c.cust_code = i.cust_code  
  WHERE employee_id = 83677 
) t2 on t1.cust_code = t2.cust_code 
ORDER BY cust_lname, cust_fname;
```